# How to use same store with different URL's in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, store

i am working in extjs. i have store as-

```
 Ext.define('Balaee.store.qb.QbqnsStore',{
            extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
            model: 'Balaee.model.qb.QbqnsModel',
            autoLoad: true,

            proxy:
            {
                type:'ajax',
                api:
                {
        read:index.php/QuestionBank/qbpaper/createpaper',

        },
                reader:
                {type:'json',
                    //root:'polls',},
                writer:
                {type:'json',
                    root:'data',
                }}});
```

So proxy's read property is set to above Url. Now i want to use this same store for some other view but with different Url for read property.So how to change store's read URL dynamically? i had tried as-
on button click event i want to read data from url-
/index.php/QuestionBank/qbpaper/Reviewquestionpaper111

So on button click function i had written as-

```
review:function()
    {
        //alert("hello");

        var QbqnsStore=this.getStore('qb.QbqnsStore');
        proxy=QbqnsStore.getProxy();
        Ext.apply(proxy.api,{
            read:'http://127.0.0.1/s_balaee/Balaee/index.php/QuestionBank/qbpaper/Reviewquestionpaper',

        });
```

I have create variable of this store and provided new required URL. Bt its not working.
So how to use same store for different views with different URL in read property.

Answer (score 3):

You can try as follow:

```
QbqnsStore.proxy.url =  'new url';
```

and this will change it's read url.be sure after changing the url you should reload your store:

```
QbqnsStore.reload();
```

Comment: Thanx sir for reply.i tried as you had said.But its not working. Its not calling this newly inserted URL.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
 var QbqnsStore=this.getStore('qb.QbqnsStore').load({url:'newUrl'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the **read** property of object **proxy**:

```
  var store = this.getStore('qb.QbqnsStore');
  proxy = store.getProxy();
  proxy.api.read = 'http://127.0.0.1/myNewUrl';
```

And then call `store.sync()` or `store.load()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

store.proxy.api.read = 'new url';